# Joomla - Display block of a tooltip not work in main menu

Tags: joomla-3.x, css

I'm trying to display a tool tip when you have your mouse over to the menu item " blog ".

My tooltip, content in the menu is this:

`< li id="newitem91">< div class="tool-tip">< span>tool tip!< /span>< /div>< /li>`

and the CSS class to display it is this , but it does not work

`#fx-item1455:hover +#newitem91 {display:block !important;}`

What could be the problem? Conflict with joomla css?

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Is it a custom tooltip or the defaukt Bootstrap 2.x one that comes shipped with Joomla?

Comment: it's a custom tooltip

Comment: `.tool-tip { display:none; } #newitem91:hover .tool-tip { display:block; }` perhaps?

Comment: But i would that when i go on button blog that has id="fx-item1455" appear the tooltip. I tried a bit of everything with css but always without result

Comment: This question is not completely clear.  Please add more of the html markup so that we can reproduce the issue.  That `+` looks suspicious.  Please progress this question toward resolution.

Comment: @Gabriel currently, you have only accepted one answer but have posted 8 questions.  Please progress your unresolved questions by accepting an answer or by editing your question to provide more relevant details.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
.tool-tip { display:none; } 

#newitem91:hover > .tool-tip { display:block; }
```

I hope this helps